# How to link the hover state of a div with the hover state of a nested div in another div?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

**Desired Behaviour**

When hovering over `.list_01_item`, the background of `.list_01_item` and the visually adjacent `.list_02_item` should change (using either a jQuery or CSS solution).

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/7tL538ng

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<div id="list_01">
    <div class="list_01_item">value1</div>
    <div class="list_01_item">value1</div>
    <div class="list_01_item">value1</div><!-- the hover state of this -->
    <div class="list_01_item">value1</div>
</div>
<div id="list_02">
    <div class="list_02_item">value2</div>
    <div class="list_02_item">value2</div>
    <div class="list_02_item">value2</div><!-- is the same as this -->
    <div class="list_02_item">value2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
width:400px;
font-size:0; /*to get rid of intra column padding*/
}

#list_01 {
width:50%;
display:inline-block;
background: yellow;
}

.list_01_item:hover {
background:pink;
}

#list_02 {
width:50%;
display:inline-block;
background:aqua;
}

.list_01_item, .list_02_item {
font-size:14px; /*to override container font size*/
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Updated JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/7tL538ng/3/)**

**CSS**

```
.hover {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var item1 = $('#list_01 div');
var item2 = $('#list_02 div');

item1.hover(function() {
    item2.eq($(this).index()).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

You attach a hover event listener to the div of list 1, then toggle class `hover` on the item from list 2 that got the same index as the element from list 1 that fired the event.

Comment: Wow, that was fast thanks, I had just started looking into `eq()` and `index()` but your version is a lot more concise. Thanks. (Edit:  For reference, here is another [less concise version](http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/7tL538ng/7/) which also has right to left column linking as well).